# How can I easily see whats in an object being passed to a html template

Tags: django

I am teaching myself Django, and something I have been trying to figure out is how to easily view what Django passes around in its objects and models.

For example: I am trying to tidy up the user register form I have, so I do this in the register.html:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form_line_wrapper">
    {{field}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I quickly realise that field is just the actual entry box, but I don't know what the other attributes are called (the names passed with each field).

Can someone suggest how I can easily view and navigate objects like this in Django? Or perhaps correct me if I am thinking about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the Python shell. Either start it up directly with `./manage.py shell` and import your models and examine them, or use the built-in debugger to drop you into the shell from your view by inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the appropriate point.

Either way, you can then use `dir(whatever)` to examine the properties of an object, and call whatever you like from there.

Comment: To add on to this, you can also use the debug template tag to see what's being passed to a template and what it looks like when it gets there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#debug

Answer (score 0):

Django Debug Toolbar allows you to inspect the template context (and therefore it's objects).
https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

Quite useful for developing, particularly when working in templates.